Maintaining a wet look with polyurethane finishes
I am trying to do some touch up on some oak veneered cabinets with a golden oak finish under a polyester top coat. I have been able to match the touch ups to the original without any great visible difference, but only while the surface is wet. Whether it's wet from a wipe down after sanding, wet with the oil-based stain, or wet from the oil-based top coat, it matches well while wet, but after drying, the touch up stands out.
I've sealed, stained, and filled some of these, so getting back to bare wood isn't practical. But the appearance after any or all of this when wet is usable.
Is there something I can do with the top coat to keep it looking wet? Or is there something else I could be doing?
great

What finish class/style (satin, gloss, .... ?) is your polyurethane coating supposed to have (what's written on the can)?

Are you using high gloss?

I am using [MinWax oil-modified] Warm Gloss.

Warm gloss must be a new naming convention for MinWax, never seen it until now. You may need to go with a different brand then and try a High-gloss, instead of gloss.

What are you doing to polish it after it cures? If you want a wet look, that's pretty much required. Sand up to about 2000 and then change to polishing compound. Don't start on that until the finish is well cured and fully hard.

To get a uniform sheen, you might have to just recoat the entire thing.
